# Creating subscriptions for AAD change notifications throws 'Subscription validation timed out exception" inconsistently

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Always creating new AAD change notificaiton subscription against AAD1 which was **created couple of years before** by giving azure function(consumption plan) url as call back url, works as expected by creating & returning subscription details.

While creating new AAD change notificaiton subscription against any other recently created AAD (other than AAD1 which was created couple of years before) most of the time it throws"Subscription validation timed out exception".

We may encounter "timed out" exception because of cold start of azure function which is running under consumption plan. But how come creating new subscription against AAD1 always successful? Never ever encountered "timed out" exception with AAD1 but quite frequently with any other recently created AAD. Please clarify.

Comment: Any response would be helpful. please

Answer (score 0):

There are no suitable suggestions. In this case, you should [contact Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to track the request for you.